# Getting biggest directory size on hard disk in code

Tags: c#, .net, win32-process

I have some troubles in my machine. My harddisk is about 500 GBs, and I am sure my files are no more than 150 GB. But it shows that the free space is only 100 GB. I would know what is the biggest directory in my computer, because when I tried searching with `"*.*" size:gigabytes` property it doesn't matter. I need an idea of an algorithm that searches in directory then in its subdirectories? e.g.

```
long count = Directory.GetDirectories("C:\\");
for (int i = 0; i < count.Length; i++)
{
   // I need to look in each directory and repeat process
}
```

Comment: There are [lots of free tools](http://superuser.com/questions/8248/best-program-to-visualize-file-system-usage-on-windows) to do what you want, if you don't really care about writing your own solution.

Comment: No code from me, but this always solves tracking down disk usage for me: http://www.memecode.com/idisk.php

Comment: @Blorg : thank you, I prefer to write code, I enjoy so.

Comment: It is probably `c:\System Volume Information`.  The one your program cannot read either.

Answer (score 3):

You'll either need to learn about **recursion** or use a **Stack**.

I could write out the code for you, but if you plan to write programs more often, these are essential concepts to understand.  Put in a bit of effort to understand them well.  Then, you'll be able to do this task as well as many others.

Comment: thank you, can you mention some sources to learn from, please?

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to build a program to do this, or are you just trying to use code to figure this out for your own machine?

If it is the later, [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) will save you a lot of time.

If it is the former, I suggest you look into [recursive functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29).

Answer (score 2):

I also recommend you to try to use WinDirStat, which is open-source software.
I share my experience on using this utility here, http://lazyswamp.blogspot.kr/2014/11/windirstat-for-finding-files-big-but.html.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a starting point, it will recursively call the C: drive and calculate the size of each folder. You may want to change it to suit your needs, like rather than keep a dictionary, just keep the biggest one.

```
Func<DirectoryInfo, long> calc = null;
var sizes = new Dictionary<string, long>();
calc = di =>
            {
                var childSum = di.GetDirectories().Sum(d => calc(d));
                var size = di.GetFiles().Sum(f => f.Length);
                sizes.Add(di.FullName, childSum + size);
                return size;
            };
calc(new DirectoryInfo("C:\\"));
```

**EDIT**:
To Hans point, you may want to run the program with elevated permissions to snoop in directories you might not have access to, like System Volume Information.

Answer (score 0):

You could just install cygwin and do:

```
$ du /cygdrive/c
```